# Is saying Jesus Christ a sin

Tags: halal-haram

I live in a western country and sometimes accidentally catch myself saying “Jesus Christ” when I’m annoyed or frustrated. I don’t mean to but it just comes out. Is this a sin?

Comment: Is it unintentional?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's a sin. In fact, it's even considered **shirk.** 
Essentially, what you're doing is calling out to Jesus even if you don't mean it.

> "**And invoke not besides Allah, any that will neither profit you, nor hurt you, but if you did so, you shall certainly be one of the zalimun (polytheists and wrong doers).** And if Allah touches you with hurt, there is none who can remove it but he, and if he intends any good for you, there is none who can repel his favour which he causes it to reach whosoever of his slaves he wills. And he is the Oft-Forgiving, Most Merciful.” 
> -Qur'an 10:106-107

Comment: Though it is true that invoking other than Allah SWT is shirk, there is however no reprehension in calling out someone out of grief, rememberance or when in a state of passionate love and longing.

Comment: @Afiq yes, but when it’s religious figures, like Jesus, you’re ultimately calling out to them as if they’re god.

Answer (score 0):

Jesus said (Quran, Maryam 19:35)

> “God is my Lord and your Lord, so worship Him. That is a straight path.”

In the related Gospel, we find (Mark 10:16-17)

> As Jesus started on his way, a man ran up to him and fell on his knees before him. “Holy teacher,” he asked, “what must I do to inherit eternal life?” - “Why do you call me holy?” Jesus answered. “No one is holy except God alone.

Jesus allowed to ask God in his name, but it is clear that Jesus himself taught to rely in God and only in Him.

Asking help from Jesus instead of God is shirk.

Using this expression as a filler without meaning to ask for help is considered lesser but haram, at least deeply disliked, and it should be avoided.

See the following fatwas:

https://islamqa.org/hanafi/daruliftaa-birmingham/171680/what-is-the-ruling-on-saying-jesus-christ/

https://islamqa.org/hanafi/seekersguidance-hanafi/108102/does-saying-o-my-god-entail-disbelief/

https://islamqa.org/hanafi/muftionline/132989/watching-movies-featuring-people-saying-jesus-christ-or-oh-my-god/